# Kotlin is not taking "is" as start of json key

Tags: json, kotlin, key

I am going through very strange and small issue. I have one data class which I am using for Json  parsing. That data class (Json) has one attribute

> val isExpired: Boolean

but after response creation its not taking **isExpired** as key. It's always changing it to **expried**.

```
"expired": false
```

Comment: what library are you using to parse the json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using Jackson to do the serialization? If so, then the answer would normally be that you need to annotate the property with `@JsonProperty("isExpired")`.  However in the specific case of `Boolean` properties it's not quite that, as discussed [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/issues/80#issuecomment-444386889). So actually what you need to do here is as follows:

```
data class MyClass(@get:JsonProperty("isExpired") val isExpired: Boolean)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer for simple question

```
    @get:JsonProperty("isExpired") val isExpired: Boolean
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in jackson-module-kotlin 2.10 https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/pull/256