# Boolean getter is serialized twice when annotated with @JsonProperty

Tags: kotlin, jackson

Suppose there is a class with a boolean property, its name starts with `is`:

```
    class Preferrable {
        var isPreferred: Boolean = true
    }
```

It is serialized to `{"preferred":true}`, dropping `is` part.

As mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32270422/5521491), to prevent it, we need to specify property name explicitly, using `@JsonProperty("isPreferred")` annotation.

That approach works perfectly with Java. But in case of Kotlin class with annotated property serialized form contains property duplication: `{"preferred":true,"isPreferred":true}`.

The workaround is to apply annotation to property getter. It doesn't work for data classes and as for me, this code looks a bit too much for just keeping property name as is:

```
class Preferrable {
    var isPreferred: Boolean = true
        @JsonProperty(value = "isPreferred")
        get() = field
}
```

What is the reason behind such behavior? Is it just a bug? Is there a simpler way to prevent `is` prefix dropping for Kotlin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Booleans are handled a bit differently from other data types. You need to explicitly use `@get` in the annotation:

```
@get:JsonProperty("isPreferred")
var isPreferred: Boolean = true
```

Note that this does work with data classes, e.g.

```
data class Preferrable(
    @get:JsonProperty("isPreferred")
    var isPreferred: Boolean = true
)
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54360035/kotlin-is-not-taking-is-as-start-of-json-key/54361152) question for a bit more info (and a link to where this is discussed in more detail).